# Need to make a tkinter message box display a message based on conditionals

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am attempting to make the messagebox in the callback command display the results of the conditionals as a message. So it would be like `messagebox.showinfo(title="Can you Smoke?, message=(Insert result of previous here)`. I have tried putting just `ageint` with message but that just showed me some random numbers.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox, Label, Button, StringVar

window = tkinter. Tk()#creates a new window
age=StringVar()
window.title("Are you old enough to smoke?")#title
window.geometry("300x200")#window size
window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')#icon

photo=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="images.png")#picture in said window
w=tkinter.Label(window, image=photo)
w.pack()

lbl=tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter your age.", bg="light salmon", fg="blue2")#label text & color
lbl.pack()

ent=tkinter.Entry(window, text="(Your age here)", textvariable=age)
ent.pack()


def callback():
    ageint=int(age.get())
    button_pressed=True
    if ageint >= 18:
        print('You are legally able to smoke.')
    else:
        print("You are not of legal age to smoke.")

    if ageint >= 18:
        print ("You are legally able to smoke cigarettes.")
    if ageint >=21:
        print("You are legally able to smoke marijuana.")
    if ageint >=40:
        print("You're above the age of forty,\nDo you really need to ask if you're old enough?")
    if ageint <=12:
        print("You're to young to smoke get out of here.")

    messagebox.showinfo(title="Can you smoke?",)

btn=tkinter.Button(window, text="Confirm", bg="sienna1", fg="blue2", relief="groove", command=callback)
btn.pack()

window.configure(background='light salmon')#back ground

window.mainloop()# draws window
```

Comment: Why are you even creating a program about smoking marijuana!?

Comment: The program is not meant to be about Marijuana. Smoking was just an easy open ending topic based on your age. The program is strictly for practice because I am trying to teach myself with tutorials and other resources.

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace `print` with `msg =` to assign the string to a reference:

```
msg = "You are legally able...
```

Then put the `msg` into the `message`:

```
messagebox.showinfo(title="Can you smoke?", message=msg)
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that was that easy this entire time. I really am a noob. Thank you so so much!